# Running OpenCV script on boot w/ RPi

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi, computer-vision, raspberry-pi3

I have a Raspberry Pi 3 running python 3.7.2 with OpenCV 4.0.1. I'm trying to run a OpenCV script on startup of the pi, but no methods seem to work. Every time I try to run the script from something like .bashrc, it says that it's not in the cv environment even when I put 'workon cv' above the command to run the script. Any help is much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Hello Ethan, Welcome to stack.  Can you provide more information please?  Can you get your script to work at all on your raspberry pi?  How have you installed python?  its it via apt-install or via mini-conda?  Can you provide the actual error as reported by the raspberry pi?  The more information you can provide, the easier is it for other people to help you.

Comment: @SteveCarter Sure, I installed python via apt-install, and the script works fine when I manually run it. The error itself is just an import error, saying "name 'cv2' is not defined." This shows up when I'm not in the opencv environment.

Comment: If you need more information, give let me know and I'll create a chat room to continue the conversation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd be running my python files, or any startup files in /etc/rc.local. 
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49626/purpose-and-typical-usage-of-etc-rc-local
may help with an explanation.
Also, I believe that the version of python running on startup is not the same as the version you are running when logged into the shell.
When running your script, are you just calling from the command line:

```
python myscript
```

where 'myscript' is the one you wish to execute?
I ran into a similar issue calling scripts on bootup on my linux server.  The workaround for me was to find and call the absolute path of the python version I wanted to run.

for example:
If I use the inbuilt version of python I have at /usr/bin/python3 to run a small program I created, I see this:

```
scarter@sb-gateway:~$ /usr/bin/python3 camera_sentry_beta_v2.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "camera_sentry_beta_v2.py", line 3, in <module>
    import cv2
ImportError: No module named 'cv2'
scarter@sb-gateway:~$
```

where as if I call the correct version of python where I have all the modules installed (I am using anaconda)

```
scarter@sb-gateway:~$ /home/scarter/anaconda3/envs/ne/bin/python read_temp.py
```

my script works.
Its possible that the version of python running on boot is not the same as the one running when you log onto the pi.  This could be a path issue. 
run:

```
echo $PATH
```

to get a list of paths your pi loads when you log in.  Can you run that command and provide the output please?

As an example, this is my path:

```
/home/scarter/anaconda3/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

I know I have a version of python under /home/anaconda3/bin which will run first.  I also know that I have a very different version running under /usr/bin which will not have the same modules as the former install.  In closing 2 things I'd do.  first locate the absolute path of python you wish to run and call it when running your script at boot time.  Secondly, I'd try use a different place than .bashrc to call your script from if you can.

Also, with respect to the 'workon' command.  This suggests that you have created a virtual environment to run python in.  I refer you to this example from 
https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command_ref.html

```
$ workon
$ mkvirtualenv mynewenv
New python executable in mynewenv/bin/python
Installing setuptools.............................................
..................................................................
..................................................................
done.
(mynewenv)$ workon
mynewenv
(mynewenv)$
```

if you created an environment as above for example, then python needs to be called from `mynewenv/bin/python`

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, I got my issue fixed by moving my commands into a shell script and calling the shell script in .bashrc.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this script on autostart on the LEXD-pi folder

go to `./home/pi/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/`

`sudo nano autostart`

```sh
    @lxpanel --profile LXDE
    @pcmanfm --desktop --profile LXDE
    @xscreensaver -no-splash
    @/usr/bin/[python3/python] [your script address]
```

run your script affter start xstart

More about this topic:

[Top issue on raspberrypi.stackexchange](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/8734/execute-script-on-start-up),
[link for detial on raspberrypi forums](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=132637)